# Decorating a plot from a plot table with tikz (plotting generic points)

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I want to plot a so called “generic point” of a curve, where the curve itself is plotted form a gnuplot table `curve.table` using `tikz`. This basically amounts to morphing a plot to be wavy or curly.

A generic point is a concept in algebraic geometry respresenting a point that is “everywhere” on a curve. It is often respresented by either some ultra-thick dot on the curve, or scattered dots of various sizes or by some wavy, curly or coiling line. Unfortunately (and shockingly), the only example of this sort of visualization I could find within five minutes is this from [wiki/Zariski Topology#Examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zariski_topology#Examples):
[image: coiling generic point]

I would prefer a wavy line or some scattering dots, but I guess this would be fine, too.

Here’s an example of what I have so far:

```
\documentclass[border=3]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw plot[smooth,scale=0.5] file {curve.table};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here, `curve.table` refers to a parabola I have generated using `gnuplot`, the data is here on [pastebin/ZJDWcXcc](https://pastebin.com/ZJDWcXcc) if you need it. This tex code hence produces the following:

[image: parabola]

> I want to modify that parabola so it’s wiggly / wavy / curly / coiling or has some scattered dots on it. How do I do this?

Tikz’ facilities for *decorating* are a candidate. The problem is that tikz only seems to be able to decorate paths. I also don’t want to plot with tikz itself because tikz doesn’t seem to be able to plot zero sets of equations (or is it?), and as the curves are getting more complicated, parametrizing them just isn’t an option …

Comment: can you state the graphics problem more and math problem less for a larger audience?

Comment: @percusse Not sure – the math part of the question is two sentences. (I put it in (and in the title) because I reckon that may be a fairly common use case.) The statement of actual problem is prominently quoted and should be clear. Or isn’t it? “Make that parabola wiggly somehow …”

Comment: That's easy just decorate it by using `plot`but I don't think that's what you are after

Comment: @percusse Decorating it didn’t work because it couldn’t recognize the plot as a path. Can you provide an example? Maybe I’m getting the syntax wrong.

Comment: You could use `\draw[decorate,decoration={random steps}] plot[scale=0.5] file {curve.table};`

Comment: @HenriMenke Oh. I was probably too tired yesterday. I tried this, but it produced an error. I obviously got something wrong because today, it compiles just fine. Thanks!

Comment: @k.stm No, you're right, it couldn't have compiled.  Mine only compiles because I removed `smooth`.  Trying to decorate smoothed paths always throws `Dimension too large`.

Comment: @HenriMenke Ah, yes. That was the problem. The compiled curve with coils also is very disconnected and doesn’t look like what one would expect. (It still suffices as a visualization for generic points even though it’s ugly.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The disconnects your are talking about in your last comment below your question come from the segmented nature of `curve.table`. It contains a segment from the end, then one befor that and so on. So TikZ starts decorating for each segment.

By sorting the table, everything is decorated as one piece and the disconnects are gone.

[image]

The sorting was done with

```
sort -h curve.table > curve-sorted.table
```

under Linux. Then I removed empty lines and comment lines in the middle with a text editor.

The code:

```
\documentclass[border=3]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[decorate,decoration={coil,aspect=0.8,amplitude=1.5pt,segment length=2.5pt}] plot[scale=0.5] file {curve.table};
    \node at (0,-0.5) {unsorted};
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{1cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[decorate,decoration={coil,aspect=0.8,amplitude=1.5pt,segment length=2.5pt}] plot[scale=0.5] file {curve-sorted.table};
    \node at (0,-0.5) {sorted};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

curve-sorted.table

```
-2.00000 4.00000 0.00000 
-1.99747 3.98998 0.00000 
-1.99494 3.97996 0.00000 
-1.99241 3.96994 0.00000 
-1.98988 3.95992 0.00000 
-1.98735 3.94990 0.00000 
-1.98482 3.93988 0.00000 
-1.98229 3.92986 0.00000 
-1.97976 3.91984 0.00000 
-1.97722 3.90982 0.00000 
-1.97469 3.89980 0.00000 
-1.97216 3.88978 0.00000 
-1.96963 3.87976 0.00000 
-1.96710 3.86974 0.00000 
-1.96457 3.85972 0.00000 
-1.96204 3.84970 0.00000 
-1.95960 3.84002 0.00000 
-1.95951 3.83968 0.00000 
-1.95693 3.82966 0.00000 
-1.95434 3.81964 0.00000 
-1.95176 3.80962 0.00000 
-1.94918 3.79960 0.00000 
-1.94659 3.78958 0.00000 
-1.94401 3.77956 0.00000 
-1.94143 3.76954 0.00000 
-1.93884 3.75952 0.00000 
-1.93626 3.74950 0.00000 
-1.93368 3.73948 0.00000 
-1.93109 3.72946 0.00000 
-1.92851 3.71944 0.00000 
-1.92593 3.70942 0.00000 
-1.92334 3.69940 0.00000 
-1.92076 3.68938 0.00000 
-1.91919 3.68330 0.00000 
-1.91815 3.67936 0.00000 
-1.91552 3.66934 0.00000 
-1.91288 3.65932 0.00000 
-1.91024 3.64930 0.00000 
-1.90760 3.63928 0.00000 
-1.90496 3.62926 0.00000 
-1.90233 3.61924 0.00000 
-1.89969 3.60922 0.00000 
-1.89705 3.59920 0.00000 
-1.89441 3.58918 0.00000 
-1.89177 3.57916 0.00000 
-1.88913 3.56914 0.00000 
-1.88650 3.55912 0.00000 
-1.88386 3.54910 0.00000 
-1.88122 3.53908 0.00000 
-1.87879 3.52984 0.00000 
-1.87858 3.52906 0.00000 
-1.87588 3.51904 0.00000 
-1.87319 3.50902 0.00000 
-1.87049 3.49900 0.00000 
-1.86779 3.48898 0.00000 
-1.86510 3.47896 0.00000 
-1.86240 3.46894 0.00000 
-1.85971 3.45892 0.00000 
-1.85701 3.44890 0.00000 
-1.85432 3.43888 0.00000 
-1.85162 3.42886 0.00000 
-1.84892 3.41884 0.00000 
-1.84623 3.40882 0.00000 
-1.84353 3.39880 0.00000 
-1.84084 3.38878 0.00000 
-1.83838 3.37966 0.00000 
-1.83814 3.37876 0.00000 
-1.83538 3.36874 0.00000 
-1.83263 3.35872 0.00000 
-1.82987 3.34870 0.00000 
-1.82711 3.33868 0.00000 
-1.82436 3.32866 0.00000 
-1.82160 3.31864 0.00000 
-1.81885 3.30862 0.00000 
-1.81609 3.29860 0.00000 
-1.81334 3.28858 0.00000 
-1.81058 3.27856 0.00000 
-1.80783 3.26854 0.00000 
-1.80507 3.25852 0.00000 
-1.80232 3.24850 0.00000 
-1.79956 3.23848 0.00000 
-1.79798 3.23273 0.00000 
-1.79678 3.22846 0.00000 
-1.79396 3.21844 0.00000 
-1.79114 3.20842 0.00000 
-1.78832 3.19840 0.00000 
-1.78551 3.18838 0.00000 
-1.78269 3.17836 0.00000 
-1.77987 3.16834 0.00000 
-1.77705 3.15832 0.00000 
-1.77423 3.14830 0.00000 
-1.77141 3.13828 0.00000 
-1.76860 3.12826 0.00000 
-1.76578 3.11824 0.00000 
-1.76296 3.10822 0.00000 
-1.76014 3.09820 0.00000 
-1.75758 3.08907 0.00000 
-1.75732 3.08818 0.00000 
-1.75443 3.07816 0.00000
-1.75443 3.07816 0.00000 
-1.75155 3.06814 0.00000 
-1.74867 3.05812 0.00000 
-1.74578 3.04810 0.00000 
-1.74290 3.03808 0.00000 
-1.74002 3.02806 0.00000 
-1.73713 3.01804 0.00000 
-1.73425 3.00802 0.00000 
-1.73136 2.99800 0.00000 
-1.72848 2.98798 0.00000 
-1.72560 2.97796 0.00000 
-1.72271 2.96794 0.00000 
-1.71983 2.95792 0.00000 
-1.71717 2.94868 0.00000 
-1.71694 2.94790 0.00000 
-1.71399 2.93788 0.00000 
-1.71104 2.92786 0.00000 
-1.70808 2.91784 0.00000 
-1.70513 2.90782 0.00000 
-1.70218 2.89780 0.00000 
-1.69923 2.88778 0.00000 
-1.69627 2.87776 0.00000 
-1.69332 2.86774 0.00000 
-1.69037 2.85772 0.00000 
-1.68742 2.84770 0.00000 
-1.68447 2.83768 0.00000 
-1.68151 2.82766 0.00000 
-1.67856 2.81764 0.00000 
-1.67677 2.81155 0.00000 
-1.67558 2.80762 0.00000 
-1.67256 2.79760 0.00000 
-1.66953 2.78758 0.00000 
-1.66651 2.77756 0.00000 
-1.66348 2.76754 0.00000 
-1.66046 2.75752 0.00000 
-1.65743 2.74749 0.00000 
-1.65441 2.73747 0.00000 
-1.65139 2.72745 0.00000 
-1.64836 2.71743 0.00000 
-1.64534 2.70741 0.00000 
-1.64231 2.69739 0.00000 
-1.63929 2.68737 0.00000 
-1.63636 2.67769 0.00000 
-1.63626 2.67735 0.00000 
-1.63316 2.66733 0.00000 
-1.63006 2.65731 0.00000 
-1.62696 2.64729 0.00000 
-1.62386 2.63727 0.00000 
-1.62076 2.62725 0.00000 
-1.61766 2.61723 0.00000 
-1.61456 2.60721 0.00000 
-1.61146 2.59719 0.00000 
-1.60836 2.58717 0.00000 
-1.60526 2.57715 0.00000 
-1.60216 2.56713 0.00000 
-1.59906 2.55711 0.00000 
-1.59596 2.54709 0.00000 
-1.59278 2.53707 0.00000 
-1.58960 2.52705 0.00000 
-1.58642 2.51703 0.00000 
-1.58324 2.50701 0.00000 
-1.58006 2.49699 0.00000 
-1.57689 2.48697 0.00000 
-1.57371 2.47695 0.00000 
-1.57053 2.46693 0.00000 
-1.56735 2.45691 0.00000 
-1.56417 2.44689 0.00000 
-1.56099 2.43687 0.00000 
-1.55781 2.42685 0.00000 
-1.55556 2.41975 0.00000 
-1.55460 2.41683 0.00000 
-1.55134 2.40681 0.00000 
-1.54808 2.39679 0.00000 
-1.54482 2.38677 0.00000 
-1.54155 2.37675 0.00000 
-1.53829 2.36673 0.00000 
-1.53503 2.35671 0.00000 
-1.53176 2.34669 0.00000 
-1.52850 2.33667 0.00000 
-1.52524 2.32665 0.00000 
-1.52197 2.31663 0.00000 
-1.51871 2.30661 0.00000 
-1.51545 2.29659 0.00000 
-1.51515 2.29568 0.00000 
-1.51210 2.28657 0.00000 
-1.50875 2.27655 0.00000 
-1.50540 2.26653 0.00000 
-1.50205 2.25651 0.00000 
-1.49870 2.24649 0.00000 
-1.49535 2.23647 0.00000 
-1.49200 2.22645 0.00000 
-1.48865 2.21643 0.00000 
-1.48529 2.20641 0.00000 
-1.48194 2.19639 0.00000 
-1.47859 2.18637 0.00000 
-1.47524 2.17635 0.00000 
-1.47475 2.17488 0.00000 
-1.47181 2.16633 0.00000 
-1.46836 2.15631 0.00000 
-1.46836 2.15631 0.00000 
-1.46492 2.14629 0.00000 
-1.46148 2.13627 0.00000 
-1.45803 2.12625 0.00000 
-1.45459 2.11623 0.00000 
-1.45114 2.10621 0.00000 
-1.44770 2.09619 0.00000 
-1.44425 2.08617 0.00000 
-1.44081 2.07615 0.00000 
-1.43737 2.06613 0.00000 
-1.43434 2.05734 0.00000 
-1.43391 2.05611 0.00000 
-1.43037 2.04609 0.00000 
-1.42682 2.03607 0.00000 
-1.42328 2.02605 0.00000 
-1.41974 2.01603 0.00000 
-1.41619 2.00601 0.00000 
-1.41265 1.99599 0.00000 
-1.40911 1.98597 0.00000 
-1.40557 1.97595 0.00000 
-1.40202 1.96593 0.00000 
-1.39848 1.95591 0.00000 
-1.39494 1.94589 0.00000 
-1.39394 1.94307 0.00000 
-1.39132 1.93587 0.00000 
-1.38767 1.92585 0.00000 
-1.38403 1.91583 0.00000 
-1.38038 1.90581 0.00000 
-1.37673 1.89579 0.00000 
-1.37309 1.88577 0.00000 
-1.36944 1.87575 0.00000 
-1.36579 1.86573 0.00000 
-1.36214 1.85571 0.00000 
-1.35850 1.84569 0.00000 
-1.35485 1.83567 0.00000 
-1.35354 1.83206 0.00000 
-1.35113 1.82565 0.00000 
-1.34738 1.81563 0.00000 
-1.34362 1.80561 0.00000 
-1.33986 1.79559 0.00000 
-1.33610 1.78557 0.00000 
-1.33235 1.77555 0.00000 
-1.32859 1.76553 0.00000 
-1.32483 1.75551 0.00000 
-1.32107 1.74549 0.00000 
-1.31732 1.73547 0.00000 
-1.31356 1.72545 0.00000 
-1.31313 1.72431 0.00000 
-1.30970 1.71543 0.00000 
-1.30582 1.70541 0.00000 
-1.30195 1.69539 0.00000 
-1.29807 1.68537 0.00000 
-1.29420 1.67535 0.00000 
-1.29032 1.66533 0.00000 
-1.28645 1.65531 0.00000 
-1.28257 1.64529 0.00000 
-1.27870 1.63527 0.00000 
-1.27482 1.62525 0.00000 
-1.27273 1.61983 0.00000 
-1.27089 1.61523 0.00000 
-1.26689 1.60521 0.00000 
-1.26289 1.59519 0.00000 
-1.25889 1.58517 0.00000 
-1.25489 1.57515 0.00000 
-1.25089 1.56513 0.00000 
-1.24689 1.55511 0.00000 
-1.24289 1.54509 0.00000 
-1.23889 1.53507 0.00000 
-1.23489 1.52505 0.00000 
-1.23232 1.51862 0.00000 
-1.23084 1.51503 0.00000 
-1.22671 1.50501 0.00000 
-1.22258 1.49499 0.00000 
-1.21844 1.48497 0.00000 
-1.21431 1.47495 0.00000 
-1.21018 1.46493 0.00000 
-1.20604 1.45491 0.00000 
-1.20191 1.44489 0.00000 
-1.19778 1.43487 0.00000 
-1.19364 1.42485 0.00000 
-1.19192 1.42067 0.00000 
-1.18943 1.41483 0.00000 
-1.18515 1.40481 0.00000 
-1.18087 1.39479 0.00000 
-1.17660 1.38477 0.00000 
-1.17232 1.37475 0.00000 
-1.16805 1.36473 0.00000 
-1.16377 1.35471 0.00000 
-1.15950 1.34469 0.00000 
-1.15522 1.33467 0.00000 
-1.15152 1.32599 0.00000 
-1.15092 1.32465 0.00000 
-1.14650 1.31463 0.00000 
-1.14207 1.30461 0.00000 
-1.13764 1.29459 0.00000 
-1.13321 1.28457 0.00000 
-1.12878 1.27455 0.00000 
-1.12435 1.26453 0.00000 
-1.11992 1.25451 0.00000 
-1.11992 1.25451 0.00000 
-1.11550 1.24449 0.00000 
-1.11111 1.23457 0.00000 
-1.11107 1.23447 0.00000 
-1.10647 1.22445 0.00000 
-1.10188 1.21443 0.00000 
-1.09729 1.20441 0.00000 
-1.09270 1.19439 0.00000 
-1.08810 1.18437 0.00000 
-1.08351 1.17435 0.00000 
-1.07892 1.16433 0.00000 
-1.07433 1.15431 0.00000 
-1.07071 1.14641 0.00000 
-1.06970 1.14429 0.00000 
-1.06493 1.13427 0.00000 
-1.06016 1.12425 0.00000 
-1.05539 1.11423 0.00000 
-1.05062 1.10421 0.00000 
-1.04585 1.09419 0.00000 
-1.04108 1.08417 0.00000 
-1.03631 1.07415 0.00000 
-1.03154 1.06413 0.00000 
-1.03030 1.06152 0.00000 
-1.02663 1.05411 0.00000 
-1.02167 1.04409 0.00000 
-1.01671 1.03407 0.00000 
-1.01175 1.02405 0.00000 
-1.00679 1.01403 0.00000 
-1.00183 1.00401 0.00000 
-0.99687 0.99399 0.00000 
-0.99191 0.98397 0.00000 
-0.98990 0.97990 0.00000 
-0.98683 0.97395 0.00000 
-0.98166 0.96393 0.00000 
-0.97650 0.95391 0.00000 
-0.97133 0.94389 0.00000 
-0.96616 0.93387 0.00000 
-0.96100 0.92385 0.00000 
-0.95583 0.91383 0.00000 
-0.95066 0.90381 0.00000 
-0.94949 0.90154 0.00000 
-0.94532 0.89379 0.00000 
-0.93993 0.88377 0.00000 
-0.93454 0.87375 0.00000 
-0.92915 0.86373 0.00000 
-0.92376 0.85371 0.00000 
-0.91837 0.84369 0.00000 
-0.91298 0.83367 0.00000 
-0.90909 0.82645 0.00000 
-0.90752 0.82365 0.00000 
-0.90188 0.81363 0.00000 
-0.89624 0.80361 0.00000 
-0.89061 0.79359 0.00000 
-0.88497 0.78357 0.00000 
-0.87934 0.77355 0.00000 
-0.87370 0.76353 0.00000 
-0.86869 0.75462 0.00000 
-0.86803 0.75351 0.00000 
-0.86213 0.74349 0.00000 
-0.85622 0.73347 0.00000 
-0.85032 0.72345 0.00000 
-0.84441 0.71343 0.00000 
-0.83851 0.70341 0.00000 
-0.83260 0.69339 0.00000 
-0.82828 0.68605 0.00000 
-0.82662 0.68337 0.00000 
-0.82042 0.67335 0.00000 
-0.81422 0.66333 0.00000 
-0.80802 0.65331 0.00000 
-0.80182 0.64329 0.00000 
-0.79562 0.63327 0.00000 
-0.78942 0.62325 0.00000 
-0.78788 0.62075 0.00000 
-0.78298 0.61323 0.00000 
-0.77645 0.60321 0.00000 
-0.76992 0.59319 0.00000 
-0.76340 0.58317 0.00000 
-0.75687 0.57315 0.00000 
-0.75035 0.56313 0.00000 
-0.74747 0.55872 0.00000 
-0.74362 0.55311 0.00000 
-0.73673 0.54309 0.00000 
-0.72984 0.53307 0.00000 
-0.72295 0.52305 0.00000 
-0.71606 0.51303 0.00000 
-0.70917 0.50301 0.00000 
-0.70707 0.49995 0.00000 
-0.70200 0.49299 0.00000 
-0.69471 0.48297 0.00000 
-0.68741 0.47295 0.00000 
-0.68012 0.46293 0.00000 
-0.67283 0.45291 0.00000 
-0.66667 0.44444 0.00000 
-0.66546 0.44289 0.00000 
-0.65771 0.43287 0.00000 
-0.64996 0.42285 0.00000 
-0.64221 0.41283 0.00000 
-0.63446 0.40281 0.00000 
-0.62671 0.39279 0.00000 
-0.62671 0.39279 0.00000 
-0.62626 0.39220 0.00000 
-0.61848 0.38277 0.00000 
-0.61021 0.37275 0.00000 
-0.60194 0.36273 0.00000 
-0.59368 0.35271 0.00000 
-0.58586 0.34323 0.00000 
-0.58538 0.34269 0.00000 
-0.57652 0.33267 0.00000 
-0.56766 0.32265 0.00000 
-0.55881 0.31263 0.00000 
-0.54995 0.30261 0.00000 
-0.54545 0.29752 0.00000 
-0.54076 0.29259 0.00000 
-0.53122 0.28257 0.00000 
-0.52168 0.27255 0.00000 
-0.51214 0.26253 0.00000 
-0.50505 0.25508 0.00000 
-0.50240 0.25251 0.00000 
-0.49207 0.24248 0.00000 
-0.48173 0.23246 0.00000 
-0.47140 0.22244 0.00000 
-0.46465 0.21590 0.00000 
-0.46074 0.21242 0.00000 
-0.44947 0.20240 0.00000 
-0.43820 0.19238 0.00000 
-0.42692 0.18236 0.00000 
-0.42424 0.17998 0.00000 
-0.41479 0.17234 0.00000 
-0.40239 0.16232 0.00000 
-0.38999 0.15230 0.00000 
-0.38384 0.14733 0.00000 
-0.37690 0.14228 0.00000 
-0.36312 0.13226 0.00000 
-0.34934 0.12224 0.00000 
-0.34343 0.11795 0.00000 
-0.33458 0.11222 0.00000 
-0.31908 0.10220 0.00000 
-0.30358 0.09218 0.00000 
-0.30303 0.09183 0.00000 
-0.28595 0.08216 0.00000 
-0.26823 0.07214 0.00000 
-0.26263 0.06897 0.00000 
-0.24850 0.06212 0.00000 
-0.22784 0.05210 0.00000 
-0.22222 0.04938 0.00000 
-0.20416 0.04208 0.00000 
-0.18182 0.03306 0.00000 
-0.17874 0.03206 0.00000 
-0.14774 0.02204 0.00000 
-0.14141 0.02000 0.00000 
-0.10852 0.01202 0.00000 
-0.10101 0.01020 0.00000 
-0.06061 0.00367 0.00000 
-0.03995 0.00200 0.00000 
-0.02020 0.00041 0.00000 
0.02020 0.00041 0.00000 
0.03995 0.00200 0.00000 
0.06061 0.00367 0.00000 
0.10101 0.01020 0.00000 
0.10852 0.01202 0.00000 
0.14141 0.02000 0.00000 
0.14774 0.02204 0.00000 
0.17874 0.03206 0.00000 
0.18182 0.03306 0.00000 
0.20416 0.04208 0.00000 
0.22222 0.04938 0.00000 
0.22784 0.05210 0.00000 
0.24850 0.06212 0.00000 
0.26263 0.06897 0.00000 
0.26823 0.07214 0.00000 
0.28595 0.08216 0.00000 
0.30303 0.09183 0.00000 
0.30358 0.09218 0.00000 
0.31908 0.10220 0.00000 
0.33458 0.11222 0.00000 
0.34343 0.11795 0.00000 
0.34934 0.12224 0.00000 
0.36312 0.13226 0.00000 
0.37690 0.14228 0.00000 
0.38384 0.14733 0.00000 
0.38999 0.15230 0.00000 
0.40239 0.16232 0.00000 
0.41479 0.17234 0.00000 
0.42424 0.17998 0.00000 
0.42692 0.18236 0.00000 
0.43820 0.19238 0.00000 
0.44947 0.20240 0.00000 
0.46074 0.21242 0.00000 
0.46465 0.21590 0.00000 
0.47140 0.22244 0.00000 
0.48173 0.23246 0.00000 
0.49207 0.24248 0.00000 
0.50240 0.25251 0.00000 
0.50505 0.25508 0.00000 
0.51214 0.26253 0.00000 
0.52168 0.27255 0.00000 
0.53122 0.28257 0.00000 
0.54076 0.29259 0.00000 
0.54076 0.29259 0.00000 
0.54545 0.29752 0.00000 
0.54995 0.30261 0.00000 
0.55881 0.31263 0.00000 
0.56766 0.32265 0.00000 
0.57652 0.33267 0.00000 
0.58538 0.34269 0.00000 
0.58586 0.34323 0.00000 
0.59368 0.35271 0.00000 
0.60194 0.36273 0.00000 
0.61021 0.37275 0.00000 
0.61848 0.38277 0.00000 
0.62626 0.39220 0.00000 
0.62671 0.39279 0.00000 
0.63446 0.40281 0.00000 
0.64221 0.41283 0.00000 
0.64996 0.42285 0.00000 
0.65771 0.43287 0.00000 
0.66546 0.44289 0.00000 
0.66667 0.44444 0.00000 
0.67283 0.45291 0.00000 
0.68012 0.46293 0.00000 
0.68741 0.47295 0.00000 
0.69471 0.48297 0.00000 
0.70200 0.49299 0.00000 
0.70707 0.49995 0.00000 
0.70917 0.50301 0.00000 
0.71606 0.51303 0.00000 
0.72295 0.52305 0.00000 
0.72984 0.53307 0.00000 
0.73673 0.54309 0.00000 
0.74362 0.55311 0.00000 
0.74747 0.55872 0.00000 
0.75035 0.56313 0.00000 
0.75687 0.57315 0.00000 
0.76340 0.58317 0.00000 
0.76992 0.59319 0.00000 
0.77645 0.60321 0.00000 
0.78298 0.61323 0.00000 
0.78788 0.62075 0.00000 
0.78942 0.62325 0.00000 
0.79562 0.63327 0.00000 
0.80182 0.64329 0.00000 
0.80802 0.65331 0.00000 
0.81422 0.66333 0.00000 
0.82042 0.67335 0.00000 
0.82662 0.68337 0.00000 
0.82828 0.68605 0.00000 
0.83260 0.69339 0.00000 
0.83851 0.70341 0.00000 
0.84441 0.71343 0.00000 
0.85032 0.72345 0.00000 
0.85622 0.73347 0.00000 
0.86213 0.74349 0.00000 
0.86803 0.75351 0.00000 
0.86869 0.75462 0.00000 
0.87370 0.76353 0.00000 
0.87934 0.77355 0.00000 
0.88497 0.78357 0.00000 
0.89061 0.79359 0.00000 
0.89624 0.80361 0.00000 
0.90188 0.81363 0.00000 
0.90752 0.82365 0.00000 
0.90909 0.82645 0.00000 
0.91298 0.83367 0.00000 
0.91837 0.84369 0.00000 
0.92376 0.85371 0.00000 
0.92915 0.86373 0.00000 
0.93454 0.87375 0.00000 
0.93993 0.88377 0.00000 
0.94532 0.89379 0.00000 
0.94949 0.90154 0.00000 
0.95066 0.90381 0.00000 
0.95583 0.91383 0.00000 
0.96100 0.92385 0.00000 
0.96616 0.93387 0.00000 
0.97133 0.94389 0.00000 
0.97650 0.95391 0.00000 
0.98166 0.96393 0.00000 
0.98683 0.97395 0.00000 
0.98990 0.97990 0.00000 
0.99191 0.98397 0.00000 
0.99687 0.99399 0.00000 
1.00183 1.00401 0.00000 
1.00679 1.01403 0.00000 
1.01175 1.02405 0.00000 
1.01671 1.03407 0.00000 
1.02167 1.04409 0.00000 
1.02663 1.05411 0.00000 
1.03030 1.06152 0.00000 
1.03154 1.06413 0.00000 
1.03631 1.07415 0.00000 
1.04108 1.08417 0.00000 
1.04585 1.09419 0.00000 
1.05062 1.10421 0.00000 
1.05539 1.11423 0.00000 
1.06016 1.12425 0.00000 
1.06493 1.13427 0.00000 
1.06970 1.14429 0.00000 
1.06970 1.14429 0.00000 
1.07071 1.14641 0.00000 
1.07433 1.15431 0.00000 
1.07892 1.16433 0.00000 
1.08351 1.17435 0.00000 
1.08810 1.18437 0.00000 
1.09270 1.19439 0.00000 
1.09729 1.20441 0.00000 
1.10188 1.21443 0.00000 
1.10647 1.22445 0.00000 
1.11107 1.23447 0.00000 
1.11111 1.23457 0.00000 
1.11550 1.24449 0.00000 
1.11992 1.25451 0.00000 
1.12435 1.26453 0.00000 
1.12878 1.27455 0.00000 
1.13321 1.28457 0.00000 
1.13764 1.29459 0.00000 
1.14207 1.30461 0.00000 
1.14650 1.31463 0.00000 
1.15092 1.32465 0.00000 
1.15152 1.32599 0.00000 
1.15522 1.33467 0.00000 
1.15950 1.34469 0.00000 
1.16377 1.35471 0.00000 
1.16805 1.36473 0.00000 
1.17232 1.37475 0.00000 
1.17660 1.38477 0.00000 
1.18087 1.39479 0.00000 
1.18515 1.40481 0.00000 
1.18943 1.41483 0.00000 
1.19192 1.42067 0.00000 
1.19364 1.42485 0.00000 
1.19778 1.43487 0.00000 
1.20191 1.44489 0.00000 
1.20604 1.45491 0.00000 
1.21018 1.46493 0.00000 
1.21431 1.47495 0.00000 
1.21844 1.48497 0.00000 
1.22258 1.49499 0.00000 
1.22671 1.50501 0.00000 
1.23084 1.51503 0.00000 
1.23232 1.51862 0.00000 
1.23489 1.52505 0.00000 
1.23889 1.53507 0.00000 
1.24289 1.54509 0.00000 
1.24689 1.55511 0.00000 
1.25089 1.56513 0.00000 
1.25489 1.57515 0.00000 
1.25889 1.58517 0.00000 
1.26289 1.59519 0.00000 
1.26689 1.60521 0.00000 
1.27089 1.61523 0.00000 
1.27273 1.61983 0.00000 
1.27482 1.62525 0.00000 
1.27870 1.63527 0.00000 
1.28257 1.64529 0.00000 
1.28645 1.65531 0.00000 
1.29032 1.66533 0.00000 
1.29420 1.67535 0.00000 
1.29807 1.68537 0.00000 
1.30195 1.69539 0.00000 
1.30582 1.70541 0.00000 
1.30970 1.71543 0.00000 
1.31313 1.72431 0.00000 
1.31356 1.72545 0.00000 
1.31732 1.73547 0.00000 
1.32107 1.74549 0.00000 
1.32483 1.75551 0.00000 
1.32859 1.76553 0.00000 
1.33235 1.77555 0.00000 
1.33610 1.78557 0.00000 
1.33986 1.79559 0.00000 
1.34362 1.80561 0.00000 
1.34738 1.81563 0.00000 
1.35113 1.82565 0.00000 
1.35354 1.83206 0.00000 
1.35485 1.83567 0.00000 
1.35850 1.84569 0.00000 
1.36214 1.85571 0.00000 
1.36579 1.86573 0.00000 
1.36944 1.87575 0.00000 
1.37309 1.88577 0.00000 
1.37673 1.89579 0.00000 
1.38038 1.90581 0.00000 
1.38403 1.91583 0.00000 
1.38767 1.92585 0.00000 
1.39132 1.93587 0.00000 
1.39394 1.94307 0.00000 
1.39494 1.94589 0.00000 
1.39848 1.95591 0.00000 
1.40202 1.96593 0.00000 
1.40557 1.97595 0.00000 
1.40911 1.98597 0.00000 
1.41265 1.99599 0.00000 
1.41619 2.00601 0.00000 
1.41974 2.01603 0.00000 
1.42328 2.02605 0.00000 
1.42682 2.03607 0.00000 
1.42682 2.03607 0.00000 
1.43037 2.04609 0.00000 
1.43391 2.05611 0.00000 
1.43434 2.05734 0.00000 
1.43737 2.06613 0.00000 
1.44081 2.07615 0.00000 
1.44425 2.08617 0.00000 
1.44770 2.09619 0.00000 
1.45114 2.10621 0.00000 
1.45459 2.11623 0.00000 
1.45803 2.12625 0.00000 
1.46148 2.13627 0.00000 
1.46492 2.14629 0.00000 
1.46836 2.15631 0.00000 
1.47181 2.16633 0.00000 
1.47475 2.17488 0.00000 
1.47524 2.17635 0.00000 
1.47859 2.18637 0.00000 
1.48194 2.19639 0.00000 
1.48529 2.20641 0.00000 
1.48865 2.21643 0.00000 
1.49200 2.22645 0.00000 
1.49535 2.23647 0.00000 
1.49870 2.24649 0.00000 
1.50205 2.25651 0.00000 
1.50540 2.26653 0.00000 
1.50875 2.27655 0.00000 
1.51210 2.28657 0.00000 
1.51515 2.29568 0.00000 
1.51545 2.29659 0.00000 
1.51871 2.30661 0.00000 
1.52197 2.31663 0.00000 
1.52524 2.32665 0.00000 
1.52850 2.33667 0.00000 
1.53176 2.34669 0.00000 
1.53503 2.35671 0.00000 
1.53829 2.36673 0.00000 
1.54155 2.37675 0.00000 
1.54482 2.38677 0.00000 
1.54808 2.39679 0.00000 
1.55134 2.40681 0.00000 
1.55460 2.41683 0.00000 
1.55556 2.41975 0.00000 
1.55781 2.42685 0.00000 
1.56099 2.43687 0.00000 
1.56417 2.44689 0.00000 
1.56735 2.45691 0.00000 
1.57053 2.46693 0.00000 
1.57371 2.47695 0.00000 
1.57689 2.48697 0.00000 
1.58006 2.49699 0.00000 
1.58324 2.50701 0.00000 
1.58642 2.51703 0.00000 
1.58960 2.52705 0.00000 
1.59278 2.53707 0.00000 
1.59596 2.54709 0.00000 
1.59906 2.55711 0.00000 
1.60216 2.56713 0.00000 
1.60526 2.57715 0.00000 
1.60836 2.58717 0.00000 
1.61146 2.59719 0.00000 
1.61456 2.60721 0.00000 
1.61766 2.61723 0.00000 
1.62076 2.62725 0.00000 
1.62386 2.63727 0.00000 
1.62696 2.64729 0.00000 
1.63006 2.65731 0.00000 
1.63316 2.66733 0.00000 
1.63626 2.67735 0.00000 
1.63636 2.67769 0.00000 
1.63929 2.68737 0.00000 
1.64231 2.69739 0.00000 
1.64534 2.70741 0.00000 
1.64836 2.71743 0.00000 
1.65139 2.72745 0.00000 
1.65441 2.73747 0.00000 
1.65743 2.74749 0.00000 
1.66046 2.75752 0.00000 
1.66348 2.76754 0.00000 
1.66651 2.77756 0.00000 
1.66953 2.78758 0.00000 
1.67256 2.79760 0.00000 
1.67558 2.80762 0.00000 
1.67677 2.81155 0.00000 
1.67856 2.81764 0.00000 
1.68151 2.82766 0.00000 
1.68447 2.83768 0.00000 
1.68742 2.84770 0.00000 
1.69037 2.85772 0.00000 
1.69332 2.86774 0.00000 
1.69627 2.87776 0.00000 
1.69923 2.88778 0.00000 
1.70218 2.89780 0.00000 
1.70513 2.90782 0.00000 
1.70808 2.91784 0.00000 
1.71104 2.92786 0.00000 
1.71399 2.93788 0.00000 
1.71694 2.94790 0.00000 
1.71717 2.94868 0.00000 
1.71717 2.94868 0.00000 
1.71983 2.95792 0.00000 
1.72271 2.96794 0.00000 
1.72560 2.97796 0.00000 
1.72848 2.98798 0.00000 
1.73136 2.99800 0.00000 
1.73425 3.00802 0.00000 
1.73713 3.01804 0.00000 
1.74002 3.02806 0.00000 
1.74290 3.03808 0.00000 
1.74578 3.04810 0.00000 
1.74867 3.05812 0.00000 
1.75155 3.06814 0.00000 
1.75443 3.07816 0.00000 
1.75732 3.08818 0.00000 
1.75758 3.08907 0.00000 
1.76014 3.09820 0.00000 
1.76296 3.10822 0.00000 
1.76578 3.11824 0.00000 
1.76860 3.12826 0.00000 
1.77141 3.13828 0.00000 
1.77423 3.14830 0.00000 
1.77705 3.15832 0.00000 
1.77987 3.16834 0.00000 
1.78269 3.17836 0.00000 
1.78551 3.18838 0.00000 
1.78832 3.19840 0.00000 
1.79114 3.20842 0.00000 
1.79396 3.21844 0.00000 
1.79678 3.22846 0.00000 
1.79798 3.23273 0.00000 
1.79956 3.23848 0.00000 
1.80232 3.24850 0.00000 
1.80507 3.25852 0.00000 
1.80783 3.26854 0.00000 
1.81058 3.27856 0.00000 
1.81334 3.28858 0.00000 
1.81609 3.29860 0.00000 
1.81885 3.30862 0.00000 
1.82160 3.31864 0.00000 
1.82436 3.32866 0.00000 
1.82711 3.33868 0.00000 
1.82987 3.34870 0.00000 
1.83263 3.35872 0.00000 
1.83538 3.36874 0.00000 
1.83814 3.37876 0.00000 
1.83838 3.37966 0.00000 
1.84084 3.38878 0.00000 
1.84353 3.39880 0.00000 
1.84623 3.40882 0.00000 
1.84892 3.41884 0.00000 
1.85162 3.42886 0.00000 
1.85432 3.43888 0.00000 
1.85701 3.44890 0.00000 
1.85971 3.45892 0.00000 
1.86240 3.46894 0.00000 
1.86510 3.47896 0.00000 
1.86779 3.48898 0.00000 
1.87049 3.49900 0.00000 
1.87319 3.50902 0.00000 
1.87588 3.51904 0.00000 
1.87858 3.52906 0.00000 
1.87879 3.52984 0.00000 
1.88122 3.53908 0.00000 
1.88386 3.54910 0.00000 
1.88650 3.55912 0.00000 
1.88913 3.56914 0.00000 
1.89177 3.57916 0.00000 
1.89441 3.58918 0.00000 
1.89705 3.59920 0.00000 
1.89969 3.60922 0.00000 
1.90233 3.61924 0.00000 
1.90496 3.62926 0.00000 
1.90760 3.63928 0.00000 
1.91024 3.64930 0.00000 
1.91288 3.65932 0.00000 
1.91552 3.66934 0.00000 
1.91815 3.67936 0.00000 
1.91919 3.68330 0.00000 
1.92076 3.68938 0.00000 
1.92334 3.69940 0.00000 
1.92593 3.70942 0.00000 
1.92851 3.71944 0.00000 
1.93109 3.72946 0.00000 
1.93368 3.73948 0.00000 
1.93626 3.74950 0.00000 
1.93884 3.75952 0.00000 
1.94143 3.76954 0.00000 
1.94401 3.77956 0.00000 
1.94659 3.78958 0.00000 
1.94918 3.79960 0.00000 
1.95176 3.80962 0.00000 
1.95434 3.81964 0.00000 
1.95693 3.82966 0.00000 
1.95951 3.83968 0.00000 
1.95960 3.84002 0.00000 
1.96204 3.84970 0.00000 
1.96457 3.85972 0.00000 
1.96710 3.86974 0.00000 
1.96710 3.86974 0.00000 
1.96963 3.87976 0.00000 
1.97216 3.88978 0.00000 
1.97469 3.89980 0.00000 
1.97722 3.90982 0.00000 
1.97976 3.91984 0.00000 
1.98229 3.92986 0.00000 
1.98482 3.93988 0.00000 
1.98735 3.94990 0.00000 
1.98988 3.95992 0.00000 
1.99241 3.96994 0.00000 
1.99494 3.97996 0.00000 
1.99747 3.98998 0.00000 
2.00000 4.00000 0.00000
```

Comment: Thanks! I figured myself in the meantime, and I had to sort the data by hand because the actual curve  I was working with (*Y² - X²(X+1)*) did not have unique points for a given “*x*-value”.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to do it with TikZ, but I  propose a short code with `pstricks`, and more specifically with `pst-coil`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe, margin = 5mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pstricks-add, pst-coil}% auto-pst-pdf

\begin{document}

\noindent
\psset{unit = 0.8cm}
\begin{pspicture}(0.4,-2)(25,2)
\psset{coilheight = 1.75}
\psCoil{280}{6000}
\dotnodes[dotsize =15pt](3.1,-0.25){2}(6.60,-0.25){3}(12.375,-0.25){5}(18.56,-0.25){7}
\foreach \n in{2,3,5,7} {\nput{-90}{\n}{(\n)}}
\rput(21,1){$(0)$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That’s reproducing the example image from wikipedia (which is neat, so +1), but can you apply this for plots of gnuplot tables?

Comment: @k.stm: I don't know what are gnuplot tables. If you post a link displaying one, I  can say and try.  Anyway the coil itself is generic: it is the projection of a helix; the parameters are the starting angle and the ending angle, in cylindrical coordinates. The position of the label are determined by trial and error.

Comment: See my question: I have already provided a link to such a table on pastebin.